# android google map mysql

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-asynctask

I have a project in which want to display google map markers from a MySQL database. This is  a tracking system. The coordinates are generated by a GPS device and stored in Database. The user will click to update the markers. I'm having an error in logcat that I don't understand. Here is my code.

MapActivity.java:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment map = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map.getMapAsync(this);

        final LinearLayout drawer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_kuno);
        final Button option = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_update);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new RetrieveTask().execute();
            }
        });

        drawer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        option.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        option.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                option.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                drawer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        });

        drawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                drawer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                option.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        LatLng mab = new LatLng(10.6817889, 122.9555016);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mab).title("MAB RENT A CAR OFFICE"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mab, 15));
    }

    private void addMarker (LatLng latlng) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latlng);
        markerOptions.title(latlng.latitude + "," + latlng.longitude);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }


    public void onClick_about(View v) {

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("About us:");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Mary Sor Estraza, Faith Hope Claire Cuello Jessa Joy Cadigal Angeli Nicole Morales");
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.appicon);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground (Void... params) {
            String strUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/location_marker_mysql/retrieve.php";
            URL url = null;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                url = new URL(strUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(iStream));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) !=null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();
                iStream.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            new ParserTask().execute(result);
        }
    }

    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {
        @Override
        protected List <HashMap <String, String>> doInBackground (String... params) {

            MarkerJSONParser markerParser = new MarkerJSONParser();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {

                json = new JSONObject(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            List<HashMap<String, String>> markerList  = markerParser.parse(json);
            return markerList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            for(int i=0; i<result.size();i++){
                HashMap<String, String> marker = result.get(i);
                LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lat")), Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lng")));
                addMarker(latlng);
            }
        }
    }


    }
```

This is the error in logcat.

```
09-29 04:54:40.231    1510-1521/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.  
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:82)
            at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:96)
            at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:81)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.initContentStream(HttpEngine.java:468)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:666)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
            at    com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:811)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:776)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:667)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.w.a(SourceFile:104)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.w.a(SourceFile:67)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.a.a(SourceFile:298)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.a.a(SourceFile:134)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.b.a(SourceFile:43)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.c.b.a(SourceFile:62)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.c.a.a(SourceFile:120)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.c.a.a(SourceFile:61)
            at    
        com.google.android.gms.auth.be.cron.AuthCronService.a(SourceFile:44)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.am.run(SourceFile:135)
```